# I need a Lightbox to display multiple images at once (in one zoom area)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

Can anyone tell me if there is a Lightbox (or similar) which is able to display several images at once, i.e  5 images shown overlayed together on one 'zoom'.  More specifically, I need to display one main 'background' image with several divs (each having a background image) positioned over it.
This is for asp/vbscript pages.

Thanks in advance for any help given.